# How to hijack requests with rod (golang)?

Tags: go, browser-automation, rod

I was testing a few hours already hijack feature in [rod library](https://github.com/go-rod/rod). Response body hijacking works fine, but couldn't do the same for request body.

Here's the code I made. What I am doing wrong?

```
    router.MustAdd("*/test", func(ctx *rod.Hijack) {
        body := ctx.Request.Body()

        modifiedBody := body + "\nHello World"

        log.Println("Hooked /add:", modifiedBody)

        ctx.Request.SetBody(modifiedBody)
        ctx.ContinueRequest(&proto.FetchContinueRequest{})
        ctx.MustLoadResponse()
    })
       go router.Run()
```

I'm expecting here the request body to me modified, but its not. I'm checking by opening devtools and checking network requests with rod browser instance.